# python3.7 subprocess failed to delete files for me

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess, pytest

I have a python script using 'subprocess' running linux command to confirm my task is doing the right thing, and it worked well. But i found that at the same time it will generate some log files when running my task. So i added a clean up function to rm log files for me at the beginning. My script is:

```
def test_clean_up_logs(path_to_my_log):
    regex = path_to_my_log + ".*"   # i need this because log will append current date time when it's generated
    print(regex) # i can see it's correct
    result = subprocess.run(['rm', '-rf', regex])


def test_my_real_test():
      # This will run my real test and generate log files
```

but it turns out it did not remove log files for me after i added first test, it still have more and more logs file in my build dir. I run it using:

```
Python3.7 -m pytest /path/to/mydir
```

My question is: 
1. Why did not it work? In my second test case, i am using 'subprocess' to run a linux command and it worked fine.
2. Is this correct way to clean up log files? i cannot think of a better way to do it automatically. Thanks!

Comment: [shutil.rmtree()](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) perhaps?

Comment: @code3 : First of all, the `rm` command requires the name of the files, and does not accept any pattern (see _man rm_). Second, you can use pattern, but you have to let the pattern expand by the shell into a list of file (i.e. you have to run a command such as `['/bin/sh', '-c', ' rm YOURPATTERN']`), but even then, the pattern can't be a regular expression, as you seem to suggest by naming your variable `regex`, but must be a glob pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why did not it work?

Because the arguments that you gave to your command is passed in quotes and wildcards like `*` does not work in quotes. Currently the executed command *looks like* this:

```
$ rm "-rf" "filename.*"
```

Try this in your terminal and you will see that it will not remove the files that starts with `filename.`.

You need to pass `shell = True` to execute the command in a shell interpreter and give your command as a single string.

```
subprocess.run(f'rm -rf {regex}', shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. But why my second test passed?  it's like        subprocess.run(['aaa.tsk', '--input', FileA, '--output', FileB])     and it worked fine. Should i also use 'shell=True'?

Comment: sorry, i do not know how to make code format in my comment and tried to use 'enter+shift' so just posted it incorrectly

Comment: It's because you don't have any wildcards there. They are just *normal* strings so even if they are quoted, they did work normally. No you shouldn't pass `shell = True`.

Comment: can I understand it like only if i need shell expansion, i should use 'shell = True', or i should not use it even if it's a linux command?

Comment: Yes, if there are special symbols (like `*`, `~` etc.) in your parameters you need to pass `shell = True`. If not, then it is up to you. But if you pass, you need to give your command as `"single string"` like I did.

Comment: Thanks, but i failed to delete it when i tried to use fixture in my 'conftest.py'.   i wrote a fixture for the regex, and in my test i have "subprocess.run(''rm -rf {history_log}, shell=True)",   {history_log} is the fixture which is "/path/to/log.*", but failed to delete logs for me, where is wrong?

Comment: Put an `f` at the beginning of your string to make it an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). `subprocess.run(f'rm -rf {history_log}', shell=True)`